Thunderbird extension to add new category to maillist
I'm working on a thunderbird extension that shall add a new "tag" column to every mail in the maillist, similiar to how title/date and size are displayed. However, I'm not sure whether the API supports this, and all my attempts to manipulate the dom failed due to the XUL used internally, I suppose.
I dont have working code, but here is what I tried:
document.querySelector("#threadTree").querySelectorAll("tr")


The first querySelector already fails due to the threadTree being an xul element, which is inside a sub html document
<browser>
    <html>
        <tree-view id="threadTree">...</tree-view>
    </html>
</browser>

This is why my selectors fail, I believe.
Still, I can't wrap my head around the fact that I couldn't find any way to add a new category to the list using the API. I feel like that should be supported, and in fact it was quite easy to do in very old version of thunderbird...
